# Array is not changed after filter on javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying yo filter the numeric values of an array with this code:

```
 function getNumerics(toFilter) {
        toFilter = toFilter.filter( element =>  !isNaN(element));
        console.log(toFilter);
      }
      
      var toFilter = [1, 'z', '4', 2, 6];
      getNumerics(toFilter);
      console.log(toFilter);
```

The console.log inside the function shows a correct result but but the last console.log show the array with all the values but if I pass the array to the function why is not change? in javascript  all parameters are passed are reference , aren't it?

Comment: Do you expect `"4"` to be returned or filtered out?

Answer (score 0):

Your function should `return` the filtered Array:

```js
function getNumerics(toFilter) {
  return toFilter.filter( element =>  !isNaN(element));
}
      
var toFilter = [1, 'z', '4', 2, 6];
toFilter = getNumerics(toFilter);
console.log(toFilter);
```

Comment: Please avoid answers like *"Try this:"* or *"This should work:"*. Also I would add a wise suggestion to not mutate the input Array. But to create a new one instead.